# urllib2 answer only: why the post request does not yield a 302 response?

Tags: python, urllib2, python-2.4

**Constraint**: I do not have the option to use python 3, therefore `requests` is out of the question

I need to automate a file download task.

In Firefox I can see the request for file at this url `www.example.com/files/MyFile_2014-02-14.csv` goes like this in Developer Console:

```
14:38:33.782 POST www.example.com [HTTP/1.1 302 Found 406ms]
14:38:34.288 GET www.example.com/files/MyFile_2014-02-14.csv/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 687ms]
```

I use the following code to automate the process

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib

class SmartRedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    ''' use it to prove if I get a 302 or not'''
    def http_error_301(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        result = urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_301(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)
        result.status = code
        return result

    def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        result = urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)
        result.status = code
        return result

def main():


    proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://myproxy.local'})

    username='XXX'
    password='YYY'

    passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
    passman.add_password(None, 'http://www.example.com', username, password)
    pass_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)


    cookieJar = cookielib.CookieJar()
    cookieprocessor = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookieJar)

    srh = SmartRedirectHandler()

    opener =urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler, pass_handler, cookieprocessor, srh)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)

    data = urllib.urlencode({'username':username, 'password':password}) # To force post
    fileurl = 'http://www.example.com/files/MyFile_2014-02-14.csv'
    req = urllib2.Request(fileurl, data, headers={'Proxy-Connection':'keep-alive'})

    c = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

`c.code` is always 200 and `c.read()` only gives me content on their welcome page (only available after successful login)

Why I do not get a 302 as expected?

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple question.

In your code, like this:

```
    result = urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_301(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)
    result.status = code
```

When you get result form `urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_301`, `result.code` and `result.status` is 200, local var `code` is 301.
Then, you set `status` to `code`, which is 301.
But, `result.code` still is 200.

That's all, thanks.

Comment: Actually the methods of `SmartRedirectHandler` is not called at all. There is no 'status' field in the result